# How do I fully deploy Containerized Azure Function App with Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

Attempting to deploy a Function App on a Premium plan that serves the functions from a container. The HOWTO for this works well enough: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image?tabs=nodejs#create-an-app-from-the-image

However, when I try to deploy it using Terraform, no sale. Everything looks right but the function does not show up in the side menu (it does for the one deployed with the az CLI), nor can I hit it with Postman.

Via Resource Explorer I can see that the Functions are not being populated. Here is the HCL that I am using

```
resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "plan" {
  name                         = "${var.app_name}-Premium-ConsumptionPlan"
  location                     = "WestUS"
  resource_group_name          = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
  kind                         = "Elastic"
  reserved                     = true

  sku {
    tier = "ElasticPremium"
    size = "EP1"
  }
}

data "azurerm_container_registry" "registry" {
  name = "${var.app_name}registry"
  resource_group_name = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
}

resource "azurerm_function_app" "funcApp" {
    name                       = "${var.app_name}-userapi-${var.env_name}-funcapp"
    location                   = "WestUS"
    resource_group_name        = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
    app_service_plan_id        = "${azurerm_app_service_plan.plan.id}"
    storage_connection_string  = "${azurerm_storage_account.storage.primary_connection_string}"
    version                    = "~2"

    app_settings = {
        FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION               = "~2"
        FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME                  = "dotnet"
        DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL                = "${data.azurerm_container_registry.registry.login_server}"
        DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME           = "${data.azurerm_container_registry.registry.admin_username}"
        DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD           = "${data.azurerm_container_registry.registry.admin_password}"
        WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING  = "${azurerm_storage_account.storage.primary_connection_string}"
        DOCKER_CUSTOM_IMAGE_NAME                  = "${data.azurerm_container_registry.registry.login_server}/pingtrigger:test"
        WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE                      = "${azurerm_storage_account.storage.name}"
        FUNCTION_APP_EDIT_MODE                    = "readOnly"
    }

    site_config {
      always_on                 = true
      linux_fx_version          = "DOCKER|${data.azurerm_container_registry.registry.login_server}/pingtrigger:test"
    }
}
```

----- Updated based on answer ----
The solution was to instruct Function App to NOT use storage to discover metadata about available functions - this involves setting **WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE** to false. Here is my updated script

```
resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "plan" {
  name                    = "${var.app_name}-premiumPlan"
  resource_group_name     = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
  location                = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location}"
  kind                    = "Linux"
  reserved                = true

  sku {
    tier = "Premium"
    size = "P1V2"
  }
}

data "azurerm_container_registry" "registry" {
  name                  = "${var.app_name}registry"
  resource_group_name   = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
}

resource "azurerm_function_app" "funcApp" {
    name                       = "userapi-${var.app_name}fa-${var.env_name}"
    location                   = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location}"
    resource_group_name        = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
    app_service_plan_id        = "${azurerm_app_service_plan.plan.id}"
    storage_connection_string  = "${azurerm_storage_account.storage.primary_connection_string}"
    version                    = "~2"

    app_settings = {
        FUNCTION_APP_EDIT_MODE                    = "readOnly"
        https_only                                = true
        DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL                = "${data.azurerm_container_registry.registry.login_server}"
        DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME           = "${data.azurerm_container_registry.registry.admin_username}"
        DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD           = "${data.azurerm_container_registry.registry.admin_password}"
        WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE       = false
    }

    site_config {
      always_on         = true
      linux_fx_version  = "DOCKER|${data.azurerm_container_registry.registry.login_server}/testimage:v1.0.1"
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to hit the access the homepage (<app-name>.azurewebsites.net)? Additionally, in the Resource Explorer, do you see `linux_fx_version` set to "DOCKER|<your-image>"?

Comment: I do - the basic problem is the functions are not being surfaced from the container, at a high level that means the function list to the left is empty and any request results in a 404. My working theory is there is some switch I need to throw to tell the functionapp its using Docker (there is a slight difference between my TF version and the AZ CLI one on the Function App Settings) - I have thus far been unable to find it

Comment: If the `linuxFxVersion` is set properly and you are able to access the homepage, the Azure Functions is able to properly run your Docker image.
You image has to have Functions located at `/home/site/wwwroot`. Note, if you are using `dotnet`, `/home/site/wwwroot` should have the binaries after building / publishing your project.
You can also try running your image locally by spinning up a container and checking if you are able to call the functions. You'd want to set environment variables such as `FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION` and `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME` when starting your container.

Comment: With regard to this point, I created a Docker image and stored it in ACR. When I used Terraform to create the function app, I never experienced the functions being available. However, when, with the same Docker image, I created the Function app using the Azure CLI command it worked. I will double check this evening, but I do not believe image construction is the root cause here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create the Azure Function with your custom Docker image, I think your problem is that you set the environment variable `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME`, it means you use the built-in runtime, but you want to use your custom image. With my test, you only need to configure the function app like this:

```
resource "azurerm_function_app" "funcApp" {
    name                       = "${var.app_name}-userapi-${var.env_name}-funcapp"
    location                   = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.location}"
    resource_group_name        = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.name}"
    app_service_plan_id        = "${azurerm_app_service_plan.plan.id}"
    storage_connection_string  = "${azurerm_storage_account.storage.primary_connection_string}"
    version                    = "~2"

    app_settings = {
        FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION               = "~2"
        DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL                = "${data.azurerm_container_registry.registry.login_server}"
        DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME           = "${data.azurerm_container_registry.registry.admin_username}"
        DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD           = "${data.azurerm_container_registry.registry.admin_password}"
        WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING  = "${azurerm_storage_account.storage.primary_connection_string}"
        WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE                      = "${azurerm_storage_account.storage.name}"
        DOCKER_CUSTOM_IMAGE_NAME                  = "${data.azurerm_container_registry.registry.login_server}/pingtrigger:test"
    }

    site_config {
      always_on                 = true
      linux_fx_version          = "DOCKER|${data.azurerm_container_registry.registry.login_server}/pingtrigger:test"
    }
}
```

Then you only need to wait a while for the creation.

Comment: Just confirm, you tested the above with Terraform and saw it work? Perhaps it is time in that case, I just know its nearly instant when using the corresponding Azure CLI command

Comment: @xximjasonxx Yes, it works fine. You can also take a try and you can see the creation process.

Comment: Ran into an issue with something unrelated that I had to fix. I will mark your answer correct once I verify this

Comment: Wow. That took me some time. So, you were partially right (I will give you credit since your comment inspired me to try again).

You MUST set the WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE app setting to false for the function to not read its metadata from storage but from the container.

Comment: Learned it the hard way as well. I want to mention that there is misleading Critical risk alert in "Function App | Diagnose and solve problems" urging you to set the FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME. Don't do it to avoid the Function App stopping loading your functions..